# Есть ли аналог GridView для табличной формы записи

Tags: android, gridview

Добрый день.

У меня есть GridView, который находится в CardView.

Если не задать точного размера, то GridView отображает только первую строчку.
На форуме прочитал уже что GridView очень хитрая штука, которая экономит ресурсы.
Есть ли аналоги, которые позволяют выводить данные в табличной форме, для данных переменной длины.(строк может быть 2, а может и 10). Или есть хитрые костыли для управлению высотой GridView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:elevation="5dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    style="@style/DayStatatText"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPBlue"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="@string/day_statistic_lable_0" />
                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/ExesTable"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:numColumns="4"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:background="@color/TOrange100">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    style="@style/DayStatatText"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPBlue"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="@string/day_statistic_lable_exes_0" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/DayStatatText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/day_statistic_lable_exes_1" />
                <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                    android:id="@+id/lineChart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textDir"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="  " />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Попробуйте поставить wrap_content

Comment: это пробовал. если использовать wrap_content или match_parent  то сжимается до одной строки.Только если указываю точное значение, то тогда отображается полностью

Comment: Покажиье вашу разметку

Comment: Посмотрите ещё на `RecyclerView` с `GridLayoutManager`.

Comment: Никита Васильченко,   добавил разметку, я так понимаю, что губит все ScrollView